# Mysqli Prepared Statement in bindParam() not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Just as usual i was looking around best practices with PHP, and prepared statements seems the kind of stuff i should now how do with my eyes closed. So i started playing around with some examples i've found.

I've got this error when running the script:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   bindParam() on a non-object in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpSecurity/PreparedStatments/Insert-Multi-Binded-Params/Insert
>   Simple Method.php on line 10

Here it goes the code.

**Insert Simple Method.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO coisas (nome, telefone, bi) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

$nome = 'Fabio Antunes';
$telefone = 916810641;
$bi = 123093456;

$stmt->bindParam(1, $nome);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $telefone);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $bi);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$db->close();
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$server_host = 'localhost';
$server_user = 'root';
$server_password = '';
$server_db = 'PreparedStatements';
$db = new mysqli($server_host, $server_user, $server_password, $server_db);
?>
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here, this is similar example found at php.net, why isn't working?
PS: I think the mysqli connection isn't the problem because I've used it to do some prepared statements with SELECT SQL commands. And worked pretty well.

---

**EDIT**

The Resolution and why.

Well in the [example](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) i should use `bind_param()` for each value in the query. But thanks to Bart, he managed to solve the problem with my code.

**Where it is:**

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $nome);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $telefone);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $bi);
```

**It should be:**

```
$stmt->bind_param("sii", $nome, $telefone, $bi);
```

Now for those who might wondering what is "sii".

Well bind_param for what i see it binds the "$var" to each question mark "?" in order.

So with one `bind_param()` i can bind them all at the same time, and the normal use of `bind_param()` requires to specify the type of data being binded.

My first value to be binded is `$nome` a String, specified by the "s";

And the others `$telefone` and `$bi` are Integers for that he have "i";

For others that have a similar problem here it goes other data types (from php.net).

> i = Integer;
>
> s = String;
>
> d = Double;
>
> b = Blob;

If someone as a better explanation please post it or comment. So i can improve my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may think there's nothing wrong with the connection, but you should check to make sure:

```
$db = new mysqli($server_host, $server_user, $server_password, $server_db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("DB error: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

EDIT:

What happens when you do:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO coisas (nome, telefone, bi) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sii", $nome, $telefone, $bi);
$stmt->execute();
```

?

Is the table `coisas` spelled properly?

Comment: Good suggestion for best practice. I've tried but it didn't solved the problem. Any other idea?

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("sii", $nome, $telefone, $bi); Worked.

Comment: Its not the first i see you answering one of my questions. Thanks for the special treatment.

Answer (score 2):

do a print_r on $stmt after you get it back on line 4. Is it a real object? I am guessing no.

Comment: Not sure what that will do but. The problem was that i as using bind param for each value, i could use only just one, and i didn't mentioned the value input type (s = string | i = integer). Thanks any way.

Comment: The error indicated that the object ($stmt) that you  were calling a method of was not in fact an object. That could have occcurred inside that method, but my first guess was that it was a null $stmt in the first place.